# Can't uninstall programm

Tags: uninstallation

First: In case this is the wrong forum please let me know and I'll try to ask somewhere else for advice :-) .

Now to my question: I installed an App / Program and I'm unable to uninstall it. It is a very annoying program which always asks me to update it but I don't use it and just want to get rid of  it. When I go to the Control Panel it only offers me the option to change the program but not to uninstall it. When I click change it opens an installation Window which gives me the option to repair, modify or remove files from my PC but when I click any option it just tells me that there are no files on my PC.
Moreover, I've also tried to enter this line in Command prompt and it says that the program was uninstalled successfully but it still continues to be on my pc.

wmic:root\cli>product where name="Autochartist MetaTrader Expert Advisor" call uninstall

Please, can somebody tell me what to do in order to get rid of the program and everything related to it? Thank you! (The program is called Autochartist MetaTrader Expert Advisor)

Comment: trace the path back to where the program is installed, and see if there are any files left, if so look for something called "uninstall" or something like that (most programs have this). In the worst case, you can hardcore delete this folder and the program is "broken".

And look if this program is in your autostart

Comment: Why not ask whoever maintains that program? This looks unrelated to programming to me, so this is off-topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my best bet is that you install Microsoft Uninstalling (or something of the sort) [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d). You'll just have to grab the Autochartist MetaTrader Expert Advisor in the list it will give (if it is present. If it isn't, then it will not work) and it should uninstall.